# Click event toggling all classes rather than correct block

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some collapsed/collapsible blocks whereby the first block is open and second/third closed. They work the way I want in terms of opening and closing, but I can't get my head around how to alter the function so that the plus and minus icons change for the correct block. At the moment all change at the same time no matter which block I open or close.

How I can alter the function so that the toggled block updates the correct icon?

```
function toggleDiv(divId) {
$("#"+divId).toggle();
$('.product-toggle span.icon').toggleClass('icon-plus icon-minus')
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p><a href="javascript:toggleDiv('features');" class="product-toggle"><span class="icon icon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="toggle-title">Features</span></a></p>
<div id="features">
    Features 
</div>

<p><a href="javascript:toggleDiv('specifications');" class="product-toggle"><span class="icon icon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="toggle-title">Specifications</span></a></p>
<div id="specifications">
    Spec 
</div>

<p><a href="javascript:toggleDiv('faq');" class="product-toggle"><span class="icon icon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="toggle-title">FAQ</span></a></p>
<div id="faq">
    FAQ 
</div>
```

Comment: I think this link may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/31041401/4696809

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start off by saying no... just no!

Add the target in your markup as a data attribute:

```
<div class="product-toggle" data-target="features">
  <p>
    <span class="icon icon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="toggle-title">Features</span>
  </p>
</div>
<div id="features">
    Features 
</div>
```

Attach a listener to the `product-toggle` class like so:

```
$(document).on('click', '.product-toggle', function() {
  var target = this.dataset.target;
  $('#'+target).toggle();
  $(this).find('span.icon').toggleClass('icon-plus icon-minus');
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gcybwkww/)

Comment: Thank you, that works great. You can tell I'm useless at code! Just one thing I need to fix...at the moment upon clicking I'm sent to the top of the page, I guess because of the hashtag in the function(?). Is there anyway to prevent jumping to the top and remain in the same position on the page when clicked?

Comment: @JustinB you are correct, replacing the anchor tags with a button or a div would solve this problem.

Comment: Updated the answer to replace the anchor tag with a div.

Answer (score 0):

Note : Inline events are discouraged; you should use jQuery click handlers as you're already using jQuery.

For example (**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e9vftqfr/1/)**):

```
$('a.product-toggle').click(function(e){
    $(this).closest('p').next('div').toggle();
    $(this).find('span.icon').toggleClass('icon-plus icon-minus')
})
```

---

If you need to use inline event calls,

You need to alter the second line to get the icon for current element

```
function toggleDiv(divId) {
    $("#"+divId).toggle();
    $("#"+divId).prev('p').find('.product-toggle span.icon').toggleClass('icon-plus icon-minus')
}
```

because,

```
$('.product-toggle span.icon')
```

selects all the `<div>s`

---

or pass `this` with the click event.

```
<p><a href="javascript:toggleDiv('features',this);"...
```

and

```
function toggleDiv(divId,currEl) {
    $("#"+divId).toggle();
    $(currEl).find('span.icon').toggleClass('icon-plus icon-minus')
}
```

Comment: While that answers the question I think the whole issue can be solved in a more elegant way with event listeners.

Comment: Yes, @SargoDarya, I was in the middle of editing a jQuery handler.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something I came up with which is a more handy solution and is not using javascript in href.

```
$('.product-toggle').on('click', function(evt){
    // This will be set to the context of the current element
    $("#"+this.name).toggle();
    $(this).find('.icon').toggleClass('icon-plus icon-minus');
});
```

This requires that you give the a tags a name instead of calling the function directly. Here is a link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ttpfzrgL/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   function toggleDiv(divId) {
      var idSelector = "#"+divId;
      $(idSelector).toggle();  
      $('p').has('idSelector').closest('span.icon').toggleClass('icon-plus icon-minus');
   }
```